# After updating view through ajax call href change to destination node

Tags: views, ajax

i have a view let say dash_status all which is showing on a page at url www.example.com/statuses/share . then url becomes for hrefs like

```
<a href = "www.example.com/statuses/comment/73/edit?destnation=statuses/share">
```

Now if i update this view through ajax call, code for ajax call as follws

```
$view = views_get_view('dash_statuses_all');
$view->set_arguments(array( $type, $value));
$view->execute();       
print $view->execute_display('page_1');
```

then after updating view my href url becomes :

```
<a herf = "www.example.com/statuses/comment/73/edit?destnation=node">
```

so the destination change to node.

I don't know why this is happening and i don't want to do this.

how i can resolve this . Please Help

Edit :

After more debugging I get to know that  action after my ajax call is getting changed to ajax handler page.
action="/xyz/AjaxCalls.php" is coming from where I am creating view.
It should be the xyz/statuses/share which was page from where ajax is getting called.

Thanks 
Yatendra